# Using numpy for contains and exact match condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to create a new dataframe with the condition:
if column1 != "uuu" and column2 contains "yes" then a new column gets value "yes".
If the above doesnt match, gets value "no_match"

Example:

[image]

My code so far:

```
df['new_column'] = pd.np.where(df.column2.str.contains('yes') & np.where(df['column1']) != 'uuu', 'yes', 'no')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please copy and paste the data as text. No images please

Comment: `np.where(df['column1']) != 'uuu'` makes no sense. You want to check `df['column1']) != 'uuu'`, check on the docs what `np.where` is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only one `np.where` with chained conditions by `&`:

```
m1 = df.column2.str.contains('yes')
m2  = (df['column1'] != 'uuu')
df['new_column'] = pd.np.where(m1 & m2, 'yes', 'no match')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
def myFunc(row):
   if row['column1'] != 'uuu' and row['column2'] == 'yes':
       return 'yes'
   else:
       return 'no_match'

df['new_column'] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)
```

Comment: Perhaps OP would rather know instead what is wrong with his current approach, which with some fixing, is way faster than an `apply` with a custom function